# Dropzone.js request is empty in Laravel

Tags: laravel, dropzone.js

I am using Dropzone.js to upload multiple images in Laravel. Though Image is uploaded without any error, request is empty. Any solution for this?

HTML code

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">ISSUE DATE / VOLUME NO</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="valume_no" value={{ old('valume_no') }}></div>
   </div>
   <div class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone">
      <div class="dz-message">
         <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="message">
               <p>Drop files here or Click to Upload</p>
            </div>
         </div>                    
      </div>
      <div class="fallback">
        <input name="featured_file" type="file[]" multiple />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2"> 
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Done</button>
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Dropzone configuration

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#my-dropzone").dropzone({ 
            url: '{{ url("/news/uploadimgsaddmode") }}',
            headers: {
                    'x-csrf-token': "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    },
            method: 'post',
            paramName: "file",
            maxFiles: 100,
            maxFileSize: 100,
            acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png",
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 100,
            previewTemplate: document.querySelector('#preview').innerHTML,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            dictRemoveFile: 'Remove file',
            dictFileTooBig: 'Image is larger than 16MB',
            timeout: 10000,                        
            success: function (file, response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });        
    });
```

Laravel Controller

```php
public function uploadimgsaddmode(Request $request){      
    return Response::json(['message' => $request], 200);                
}
```

Response

```js
{"message":[{}]}
```

Comment: You're trying to send an Object with many private or protected parameters down the response; that won't work. If you change `$request` to `$request->all()` you'll already see some data getting sent back.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan Thankz for your response. But when $request->all() is used, Response is {"message":{"file":[{}]}}. Still empty

Comment: Check your php.ini for the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. Make sure both are larger than the file you're trying to upload.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan They are larger than the file I am trying to upload.

Comment: And what if you try `$request->file('file')`?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan same response {"message":[{}]}

Comment: Then I'm not sure what is wrong. Check the request in the network tab of your browser to check whether or not the files are actually uploaded, check your laravel installation, try to upload the images without dropzone.js...